# Impulse response from the transfer function

Tags: z-transform, transfer-function, homework

The discrete system has poles at points $z_{1,2} = 0.8e^{\pm{i\pi /6}}$ and $z_{3,4}=0.8e^{\pm{i\pi/2}}$, and two-fold zeros at $1$ and $-1$. The task is to determine the impulse response of the system. The wording is weird, but I assume this means the transfer function is $$H(z) = \frac{(z-1)(z+1)}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)}$$

The impulse response must then be $$h(t) = Z^{-1}\{H(z)\}$$

Based on the given poles, I can say that the impulse response is a decaying oscillation of sorts. So this is a FIR filter. Is it possible to determine the impulse response from this information without resorting to partial fractions? ( which is the next step I would take here )

Comment: This is not a FIR filter. FIR filters do not have poles (to be precise, FIR filters have as many poles as they have zeros. But all these poles are located at the origin). **This is an IIR filter** since it has poles not located at the origin. You should use partial fractions, and pay attention to the fact that you have complex conjugate poles. [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27399/63763) will help. Good luck!

Comment: Also note that there's an unknown gain factor in your transfer function. Poles and zeros only determine the transfer function up to an unknown multiplicative constant.

Comment: Does the term "synthetic division of polynomials" ring any bells?  This is clearly a homework problem -- do you have an idea of what _form_ the instructor wants the solution in?  BTW: when you have the answer, ask yourself if the impulse response actually goes to zero and stays there.